# Non-resident alien in the US working in Canada under a TN Visa - Determining sponsor for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, tn-visa

I am a Canadian citizen (and resident) who did a 4-month internship in California under a TN visa (as a non-resident alien) in 2014. I am filing out form 8843 for tax purposes, and it is asking for the sponsor of my visa. How do I determine this? Is it just the company I worked for?

Comment: The form asks for no such thing. Can you quote exactly which question on the form you're referring to?

Comment: I am referring to Part II, Q6: "For trainees, enter the name, address, and telephone number of the director of the academic or other specialized program
you participated in during 2014" - I was following this guide for interns: https://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~f2fung/f8843page1.png

Comment: You were on TN visa. You were not trainee.

Answer (score 1):

You should not fill out Form 8843. Form 8843 is for people who were "[exempt individuals](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222138)" (exempt from the Substantial Presence Test) for some part of the year. You were not an exempt individual at any point in the year.

Comment: If this is the case, I have no idea what forms to fill out for my tax returns in the US...

Comment: @Nizbel99: I don't see what not filling Form 8843 has to do with you not knowing how to file tax returns. You can read Publication 519 which is the tax guide for aliens. But basically, you didn't pass the Substantial Presence Test for 2014, so you are nonresident for 2014. You would fill out 1040NR (or 1040NR-EZ) for starters, and go from there.

Comment: Right, so I did fill out 1040NR-EZ... which means that if I am not filling out form 8843, then this is the only form I need for the Federal portion of my tax return?

Comment: @Nizbel99: Probably, if your only income is wages and you don't have any special situations.